# USB Debugging in Windows CE?

Tags: windows

**How to debug a windows CE device using USB?.   Is there any tool available to debug windows CE devices through usb?**

Comment: You need Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 and Microsoft Windows Mobile Device Center.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need TCP/Activesync to debug a winCe device.
From visual studio/Platform builder, you can select your SDK, and the corresponding device. The device may already be connected to your network, in which case, you can provide its IP address. If not, you can connect it to your PC using a USB cable. After connection, it seems to share your PC's internet connection and it will be assigned an IP.

You can set visual studio to auto-detect your device without providing a fixed IP only.

Visual studio>Tools>Options>Device Tools>Devices gives you the above mentioned settings.

Anyway, your device must be connected to your network. Though I am not sure, you might be able to fiddle with your windows settings such that when you connect your device to the USB, your PC will assign it an IP and use 'Microsoft Loopback Adapter' as the network adapter. In this case, your device will not be visible to the rest of the network, but only to you.

Comment: Installing the loopback adapter:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa463042.aspx